# jni и cpp пакеты в android проекте

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, jni, пакет

Наверное, очень глупый вопрос, но никак не могу найти на него ответа... Чем отличаются пакеты *jni* и *cpp* в проекте с Android NDK? Вроде бы .cpp, .h, Android.mk и прочие файлы для работы с нативным кодом могут располагаться и в том, и в другом пакетах?.. Или это не так? В чём тогда их различие?